# Shiny - googlevis: Tooltips for gvisPieChart

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

I am trying to create custom tooltips for a googlevis pie chart.

I have found [Using Roles via googleVis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html) but I cannot replicate a similar concept to a pie chart. See below for one of my attempts to achive this:

```
df <- data.frame(year=c("a","b","g"),pop=1:3, pop.html.tooltip=c("alpha","beta","gamma"))

  plot(
    gvisPieChart(df,options=list(tooltip="{isHtml:'true'}"))
  )
```

Moreover, I found out that the first column chart example in [Using Roles via googleVis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html) is not working properly. Although the certainty concept is working fine, the tooltips are not displayed as defined in Sales.html.tooltip column of dat dataframe.

Apparently, I am having a problem with tooltips in every other chart apart from gvisScatterChart.

Comment: I'm not sure that the tooltip can be different from the label (`year` in your example) for a pie chart. Try `options=list(gvis.editor="Click to Edit")` and you'll notice there is nothing really to edit for different labels from the legend items. You could browse the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options) but I didn't notice anything too promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible via the google visualisation api

https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=507

The way it would work with for example the column chart is:

```
g <- gvisColumnChart(df, xvar = "year", yvar = c("pop", "pop.html.tooltip")
                     , options=list(tooltip="{isHtml:'true'}"))
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer; have you tested the gvisColumnChart, gvisBarChart and the gvisLineChart cases as well? I think they don't work as well. The only case where I was able to modify the tooltiops was the gvisScatterChart.

Comment: Have added an example of how it would work with column charts.

Comment: I have successfully implemented html tooltips as you suggested above and I have also modified the content in terms of formating. I am now trying to modify the tooltip box itself (i.e the border, the background color, positioning etc but i cannot find how to achive this. Any ideas?