# Custom tooltips for gvisTimeline in the R package googleVis

Tags: r, google-visualization

## Question/TL;DR

Has anyone had success in customising the tooltip content for `gvisTimeline` in the R package `googleVis`

Scope of need:

1. Replacing tooltip with explanatory text
2. Custom HTML tooltip, a la https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content_875a2af27d7f8cce657119d51bedda48.frame?hl=en&redesign=true

### Update:

I am specifically interested in `gvisTimeline` but there are a number of stub questions about tooltips in the other charts of the `googleVis` package. I'm collating these in this question for my own reference and in an attempt to provide a useful resource for anyone looking into this:

- `gvisTreemap` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/30892289/1659890

## Details

The Google Charts documentation makes it clear that tooltips are customisable for timelines (but not some charts): https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline and https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content.

The roles vignettes - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html -  highlighted here [Shiny - googlevis: Tooltips for gvisPieChart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26376379/1659890) shows how tooltips can be customised for many of the charts in the `googlevis` package but does not include `gvisTimeline`.

Inspecting the `gvis` file on github (https://github.com/mages/googleVis/blob/master/R/gvis.R) shows that any variable including `tooltip` will be sent to the Google Chart API. Blindly I attempted to include tooltips into a `gvisTimeline` plot as follows, but to no avail:

```
datTL <- data.frame(Position=c(rep("President", 3), rep("Vice", 3)),
                    Name=c("Washington", "Adams", "Jefferson",
                           "Adams", "Jefferson", "Burr"),
                    start=as.Date(x=rep(c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", 
                                          "1801-02-03"),2)),
                    end=as.Date(x=rep(c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", 
                                        "1809-02-03"),2)),
                    Position.html.tooltip=c(rep("cats",6)))

Timeline <- gvisTimeline(data=datTL, 
                         rowlabel="Name",
                         barlabel="Position",
                         start="start", 
                         end="end")
plot(Timeline)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured that out after stumbling over https://github.com/mages/googleVis/issues/34

Here is how you can achieve it. It basically includes a modification of the gVisTimeline call to hand over the tooltips to generation of the function.

1. save and source gvis.R from the original package to your working folder (available at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/index.html)
2. save and source this modified version to the same folder (it adds a parameter "tooltips" to the functions gvisCheckTimelineData and gvisTimeline):

   ```
   gvisTimeline <- function(data, rowlabel="", barlabel="", tooltip="", start="",end="", options=list(), chartid){
     my.type <- "Timeline"
     dataName <- deparse(substitute(data))
     my.options <- list(gvis=modifyList(list(width=600, height=200),options), dataName=dataName,data=list(rowlabel=rowlabel, barlabel=barlabel,tooltip=tooltip, start=start, end=end,allowed=c("number", "string", "date", "datetime"))
     )
     checked.data <- gvisCheckTimelineData(data, rl=rowlabel, bl=barlabel, tt=tooltip, start=start, end=end)
     output <- gvisChart(type=my.type, checked.data=checked.data, options=my.options,chartid=chartid, package="timeline") 
     return(output)
   }

   gvisCheckTimelineData <- function(data, rl, bl, tt, start, end){
     if(any(c(rl, bl, tt, start, end) %in% ""))
           return(data)
     else  
           return(data[, c(rl, bl, tt, start, end)])
   }
   ```
3. Add the toolstips to your timeline input (must be called x.tooltips, where x is your Events or barlabel vector) and the tooltips parameter to the gVisTimeline function. Load the package RJSONIO (is needed for a function inside googleVis) and googleVis and enjoy your tooltips:

   ```
   library(googleVis)
   library(RJSONIO)

   source("gvis_orig.R")
   source("gvis_mod_for_tooltips.R")

   datTL <- data.frame(Position=c(rep("President", 3), rep("Vice", 3)),
                       Name=c("Washington", "Adams", "Jefferson",
                              "Adams", "Jefferson", "Burr"),
                       start=as.Date(x=rep(c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", 
                                             "1801-02-03"),2)),
                       end=as.Date(x=rep(c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", 
                                           "1809-02-03"),2)),
                       Position.html.tooltip=c(rep("cats",6)))

   Timeline <- gvisTimeline(datTL, 
                            rowlabel="Name",
                            barlabel="Position",
                            start="start", 
                            end="end",
                            tooltip="Position.html.tooltip")
   plot(Timeline)
   ```

[image: minimal example]

For HTML Tooltips, just use the HTML code as string in datTL (instead of "cats") and add the option line `options=list(tooltip="{isHtml:'true'}")` to `gVisTimeline` call:

```
    library(googleVis)
    library(RJSONIO)

    source("gvis_orig.R")
    source("gvis_mod_for_tooltips.R")

    datTL <- data.frame(Position=c(rep("President", 3), rep("Vice", 3)),
                        Name=c("Washington", "Adams", "Jefferson",
                               "Adams", "Jefferson", "Burr"),
                        start=as.Date(x=rep(c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", 
                                              "1801-02-03"),2)),
                        end=as.Date(x=rep(c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", 
                                            "1809-02-03"),2)),
                        Position.html.tooltip=c(rep('<a href="http://www.r-project.com"><img src="http://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg" alt="R logo" /></a>',6)))

    Timeline <- gvisTimeline(datTL, 
                             rowlabel="Name",
                             barlabel="Position",
                             start="start", 
                             end="end",
                             tooltip="Position.html.tooltip",
                             options=list(tooltip="{isHtml:'true'}"))
    plot(Timeline)
```

[image: HTML Tooltips]

Best regards,

sandro

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one who had trouble to find "gvis.R". If you are having the same trouble, you can find it from github.https://github.com/mages/googleVis/blob/master/R/gvis.R

Answer (score 1):

I was annoyed of Gvistimeline needing internet connection and re-built it using `plotly`:

```
install.packages("vistime")
library(plotly)
library(vistime)

datTL <- data.frame(Position=c(rep("President", 3), rep("Vice", 3)),
                Name=c("Washington", "Adams", "Jefferson",
                       "Adams", "Jefferson", "Burr"),
                start=as.Date(x=rep(c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", 
                                      "1801-02-03"),2)),
                end=as.Date(x=rep(c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", 
                                    "1809-02-03"),2)),
                color=c(rep("blue", 3), rep("red", 3)),
                fontcolor=rep("white",6),
                tooltip=c(rep("cats",6)))

vistime(datTL, events="Position", groups="Name", title="Presidents of the USA")
```

Tooltips are taken from "tooltip" column. More information: https://github.com/shosaco/vistime
[image]